# How to create an array list of strings using the .split() function?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm attempting to create a program which must abide by the following:

1. Create a class called `WordGroup` which;
2. Has an instance variable called `words`.
3. Has a constructor which takes a String. This is converted into lower case and stored in words. Use a method from the String API to make the string lower case.
4. Has a method called `getWordArray()` which returns a `String[]`. Use the String class `split()` method to separate words on " ".
5. Create two WordGroups one initialized with "You can discover more about a person in an hour of play than in a year of conversation" and the other with "When you play play hard when you work dont play at all" //these are quotes by Plato and Roosevelt respectively with the punctuation removed
6. Use `getWordArray()` to make two arrays of Strings.
7. Write two for loops to loop over the two arrays and print out each word.

I'm currently stuck on number 6. I have two WordGroups created in my main method but I am unsure of how I would assign them to the `getWordArray()` method so that they would create a string of arrays. Here is the code:

**WordGroup class**

```
public class WordGroup {

    String word;

    //Creates constructor which stores a string value in variable "word" and converts this into lower case using the lower case method.
    public WordGroup(String aString) {
        this.word = aString.toLowerCase();
    }
    public String getWordArray; {

        word =("");
        String WordArray[] = word.split("-");

    }
}
```

**Main class**

```
public class Main{

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        WordGroup firstWordGroup = new WordGroup.word("You-can-discover-more-about-a-person-in-an-hour-of-plau-tban-in-a-year-of-conversation");
        WordGroup secondWordGroup = new WordGroup ("When-you-play-play-hard-when-you-work-dont-play-at-all");

    }   
}
```

So to be clear, I want to create two array lists that use the `.split()` function to make an array of strings using the `getWordArray()` method and then print the list of arrays out. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array)

Comment: `public String getWordArray; { ... }` doesn't do what you think it does. That is not exactly what point 4 is telling you to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not compile. The right version of `getWordArray` is as follows:

```
public String[] getWordArray() {
    String[] wordArray = word.split("-");
    return wordArray;
}
```

If you don't return the assigned variable from method, `Main` class will never know about it. And corresponding main class would be:

```
public class Main{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        WordGroup firstWordGroup = new WordGroup.word("You-can-discover-more-about-a-person-in-an-hour-of-plau-tban-in-a-year-of-conversation");
        WordGroup secondWordGroup = new WordGroup ("When-you-play-play-hard-when-you-work-dont-play-at-all");

        String[] firstWordArray =  firstWordGroup.getWordArray();
        for( String word : firstWordArray) { 
            System.out.println(word);
        }
        //second loop is very similar.
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `getWordArray` isn't doing what #4 is telling you it should do. You need the square brackets `[]` after String to tell it to return an array of strings. You also do not have a return statement.

```
public String[] getWordArray() {
    return word.split("-");
}
```

How you would use this to create to arrays of strings in #6 is calling your method from the two variables you created.

```
String[] wordArray1 = firstWordGroup.getWordArray();
String[] wordArray2 = secondWordGroup.getWordArray();
```